# I have looked at various html table tutorials, both on the w3c and other websites, but I can't seem to get the colspan tag to work right

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a program guide for my online radio station, using a table, in which some programs are played at the same time each day. In that case, the cells for that row should be merged. I am totally blind, and so can't tell how this looks, but the screen reader sure doesn't read it right, which would lead me to believe that it isn't displaying right either. The content of the table is in Spanish, but that shouldn't effect the html. I have been fighting with this all morning and don't know what else to do. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.
Here is my code. I am not that good with html.

```
<table stile=“width:100%”>
   <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Lunes</th>
      <th>Martes</th>
      <th>Miércoles</th>
      <th>Jueves</th>
      <th>Viernes</th>
      <th>Sábado</th>
      <th>Domingo</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 00:00</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>00:30</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>01:00</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 Días</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>01:30</td>
      <td colspan=“7”> Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>02:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Aliento Para Tu Alma</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>02:30</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>03:00</td>
      <td colspan=“6”>Música</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>03:30</td>
      <td colspan=“6”>Música</td>
      <td> Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>04:00</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Promesas de Dios</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>04:30</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Promesas de Dios</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>05:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Momento Decisivo</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>05:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Música<br>Motivación<br>Firmes y Adelante</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>06:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”Primera Luz</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>06:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Primera Luz</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>07:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Ciencia y Tecnología<br>Ciudad Medica<br>Batuta y Pincel<br>Circulo Radial de Lectura</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Tiempos de Restauración</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>07:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Instituto Bíblico del Aire<br>Un Momento con Alberto Motessi</td>
      <td>Música<br>Un Momento con Alberto Motessi</td>
      <td>Pensemos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>08:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Visión Para Vivir</td>
      <td>Tiempos de Restauración</td>
      <td>Momento Oportuno</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>08:30</td>
      <td colspan=“6”>El Amor que Vale</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>09:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Música</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 días</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>09:30</td>
      <td colspan=“7”>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Tiempos de Restauración</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Todo es Posible<br>Un Minuto con Mariam</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>11:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 Días</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Los Megachicos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>11:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Música</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>12:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Mundo Hoy</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Dante Gebel Live</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>12:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Música</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Mundo Cristiano</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Vale la Pena</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>14:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Al Oido<br>Encuentro<br>Vida en Familia Hoy</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>15:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Conociendo la Verdad<br>Cosas de Niños, Locuras de Padres<br>De Pelos</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>16:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Juego Limpio</td>
      <td>Fuego</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>16:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>Juego Limpio</td>
      <td>Fuego</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>17:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>17:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>18:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>18:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>19:00</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>19:30</td>
      <td colspan=“5”>El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>20:00</td>
      <td>Porque Eres Mamá</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
      <td>Extremo</td>
      <td>Mundo Cristiano</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>20:30</td>
      <td>Porque Eres Mamá</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>21:00</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>>Música</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Notimisiones Remar</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>21:30</td>
      <td colspan=“2”>Música</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Más de la Vida</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>22:00</td>
      <td colspan=“4”>Promesas de Dios</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>22:30</td>
      <td colspan=“4”>Promesas de Dios</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>23:00</td>
      <td colspan=“4”>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Shockrave</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>23:30</td>
      <td colspan=“4”>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Shockrave</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=“8”><b>Hora del Centro de los EEUU (CST/CDT)</b></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've indented your code for you. It contains some errors like `<td colspan=“5”El Antivirus</td>` and `stile=“width:100%”` you should fix first.

Comment: start by using a proper editor. `“7”` are not proper quotes. those are symptoms of using a word processor (e.g. Word) to edit your code. proper html quoting uses `'` or `"`.

Comment: Looks fine to me in a browser, by the way. http://jsfiddle.net/kv7w8gyg/

Comment: Hmmm...a couple typos in the code might be throwing you off. At the top, `stile` should be `style`, and several of your `<td>` tags are missing the closing angle bracket, `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Are trying to do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g10a790n/)

Here is the corrected html

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Lunes</th>
      <th>Martes</th>
      <th>Miércoles</th>
      <th>Jueves</th>
      <th>Viernes</th>
      <th>Sábado</th>
      <th>Domingo</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 00:00</td>
      <td colspan="7">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>00:30</td>
      <td colspan="7">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>01:00</td>
      <td colspan="7">Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 Días</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>01:30</td>
      <td colspan="7"> Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>02:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Aliento Para Tu Alma</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>02:30</td>
      <td colspan="7">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>03:00</td>
      <td colspan="6">Música</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>03:30</td>
      <td colspan="6">Música</td>
      <td> Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>04:00</td>
      <td colspan="7">Promesas de Dios</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>04:30</td>
      <td colspan="7">Promesas de Dios</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>05:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Momento Decisivo</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>05:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Música<br>Motivación<br>Firmes y Adelante</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>06:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Primera Luz</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>06:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Primera Luz</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>07:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Ciencia y Tecnología<br>Ciudad Medica<br>Batuta y Pincel<br>Circulo Radial de Lectura</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Tiempos de Restauración</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>07:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Instituto Bíblico del Aire<br>Un Momento con Alberto Motessi</td>
      <td>Música<br>Un Momento con Alberto Motessi</td>
      <td>Pensemos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>08:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Visión Para Vivir</td>
      <td>Tiempos de Restauración</td>
      <td>Momento Oportuno</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>08:30</td>
      <td colspan="6">El Amor que Vale</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>09:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Música</td>
      <td colspan="2">Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 días</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>09:30</td>
      <td colspan="7">Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Tiempos de Restauración</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Todo es Posible<br>Un Minuto con Mariam</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>11:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Lectura Bíblica: El Nuevo Testamento en 40 Días</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Los Megachicos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>11:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Música</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>12:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Mundo Hoy</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Dante Gebel Live</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>12:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Música</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Mundo Cristiano</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>13:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>Sabor Latino</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Vale la Pena</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>14:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Más Vale Tarde</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Al Oido<br>Encuentro<br>Vida en Familia Hoy</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>15:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Conociendo la Verdad<br>Cosas de Niños, Locuras de Padres<br>De Pelos</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>16:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">Juego Limpio</td>
      <td>Fuego</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>16:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">Juego Limpio</td>
      <td>Fuego</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>17:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>17:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Show de la Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>18:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>18:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>19:00</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>19:30</td>
      <td colspan="5">El Antivirus</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>20:00</td>
      <td>Porque Eres Mamá</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
      <td>Extremo</td>
      <td>Mundo Cristiano</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>20:30</td>
      <td>Porque Eres Mamá</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Top 20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>21:00</td>
      <td colspan="2">>Música</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Notimisiones Remar</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>21:30</td>
      <td colspan="2">Música</td>
      <td>Al Punto con Jefrey de León</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Más de la Vida</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>22:00</td>
      <td colspan="4">Promesas de Dios</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>El Mundo de Juan Romero</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>22:30</td>
      <td colspan="4">Promesas de Dios</td>
      <td>El Sótano</td>
      <td>Música</td>
      <td>Entre Amigos</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>23:00</td>
      <td colspan="4">Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Shockrave</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>23:30</td>
      <td colspan="4">Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Shockrave</td>
      <td>Pildoritas y Reflexiones</td>
      <td>Música</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="8"><b>Hora del Centro de los EEUU (CST/CDT)</b></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have misspelled the word `style` in your code as "stile" and you are mixing html code with css code. If you are using html colspan or rowspan don't put actual numbers in quotes, quotes are for words, for example: `<td colspan=2>`